# Drag and drop images to multiple boxes

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple pictureboxes on my form and would I want to be able to drag and drop images into these boxes.  Writing a drag and drop for each one of them would be redundant, so I figure to write a couple of subs and assign Handlers to each box.  Here is what I did:

```
Private Sub frmInventoryControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each PicBox As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()

        PicBox.AllowDrop = True
        AddHandler PicBox.DragEnter, AddressOf picBoxs_DragEnter
        AddHandler PicBox.DragDrop, AddressOf picBoxs_DragDrop

    Next

End Sub

''' Drag and drop procedures to move pictures between
''' picture boxes
''' 

Private Sub picBoxs_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    'Procedure to copy the dragged picture from the
    'open window

    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

        'If the file explorer is open, copy the picture to the box
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy

    Else

        'otherwise, don't take action
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub picBoxs_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)

    'Procedure to select the pictue and drag to picturebox
    Dim picbox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim files() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())


    If files.Length <> 0 Then

        Try

            picbox.Image = Image.FromFile(files(0))
            picbox.Tag = files(0).ToString

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Image did not load")

        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

If I write the code for each specific box, it works, but if try doing as I did above, the image does not drop. My debugger did not give me an error, just nothing happens.  Where am I going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Me.Controls` will only find PictureBoxes that are **directly** contained by the Form.  If they are inside a different container, like a Panel, then they will not be found.  In that case, replace `Me` with the name of that container such as `Panel1`.

A more generic solution would be to use a **recursive** routine that finds all the PictureBoxes.  This is especially useful if the PictureBoxes in question are located in multiple containers:

```
Private Sub frmInventoryControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FindAllPictureBoxes(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub FindAllPictureBoxes(ByVal container As Control)
    For Each c As Control In container.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is PictureBox Then
            Dim PicBox As PictureBox = DirectCast(c, PictureBox) 
            PicBox.AllowDrop = True
            AddHandler PicBox.DragEnter, AddressOf picBoxs_DragEnter
            AddHandler PicBox.DragDrop, AddressOf picBoxs_DragDrop
        ElseIf c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            FindAllPictureBoxes(c)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```